# Adding Color to Vertex in VisNetwork Igraph

Tags: javascript, r, cluster-analysis, igraph, htmlwidgets

This is a more general question to this: [VisNetwork from IGraph - Can't Implement Cluster Colors to Vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882153/visnetwork-from-igraph-cant-implement-cluster-colors-in-visualization)

I have an igraph that I have converted to a visNetwork:

```
library(visNetwork)
visIgraph(igraph, idToLabel = TRUE, layout = "layout_nicely")%>%
visNodes(size = 10) %>%
visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, 
     nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

I have a list of colors corresponding to the nodes that I want to color the graph with:

The colors are as follows:

```
c("#80FF00FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#00FFFFFF" "#FF0000FF" "#8000FFFF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF")
```

How do I add these colors to the nodes of the visNetwork?

It works in a normal plot if I were to do but not in visNetwork:

```
V(igraph)$color <- c("#80FF00FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#00FFFFFF" "#FF0000FF" "#8000FFFF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF")
plot(igraph)
```

Thanks

(If you want to have the reproducible code please refer to the link I mentioned at the top of the post.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as the "group" attribute of your igraph which informs the node coloring by default. Drawing on code from your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882153/visnetwork-from-igraph-cant-implement-cluster-colors-to-vertices) :

```
col = c("#80FF00FF", "#FF0000FF", "#FF0000FF", "#00FFFFFF",
          "#FF0000FF", "#8000FFFF", "#FF0000FF", "#FF0000FF",
          "#FF0000FF", "#FF0000FF")
i96e <- set.vertex.attribute(i96e, name = "group",value = col)
visIgraph(i96e, idToLabel = TRUE, layout = "layout_nicely")
```

Comment: Hi @jac thanks for the feedback. This still didn't work unfortunately. When I test it out, the colors do not go through. Though whole graph stays black.

Comment: nevermind that did work for the example I provided. Thank you. For some reason it's not working on my actual example but this is a great start. Thanks!