# How to change the colour of a selected edge when using the visNetwork package in R?

Tags: r, visnetwork

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006694/how-to-change-colour-of-selected-node-or-edge-when-using-the-visnetwork-package) question earlier about how to change the colour of selected nodes and edges when using the `visNetwork` package in R. The linked question helps me colour the nodes and edges, however I am making a new question as the previous one doesn't address a new issue Im facing.

In the code below Im creating a simple network. But Im also adding a column to my data that conditionally colours the edges. When I include this column, my edges are initially coloured correctly, however when I select/hover/highlight an edge it doesn't change colour. It just seems to make the edge thicker but keeps the same colour.

Any suggestions as to how I would do this?

```
library(visNetwork)

# Create example data
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4, label = c("Node 1", "Node 2", "Node 3", "Node 4"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), to = c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4), value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
edges$color <- ifelse(edges$value <= 20, "blue", "red")

# Create visNetwork object with customized node and edge colors
visNetwork(nodes, edges) |>  
  visNodes(color = list(background = "skyblue", border = "black", highlight = "yellow",
                        hover = "yellow")) |> 
  visEdges(color = list(highlight = "yellow", 
                        hover = "yellow"), smooth = FALSE)|>
  visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, hover = T),
             nodesIdSelection = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right idea! The problem is that `edges$color <- ifelse(edges$value <= 20, "blue", "red")` sets the initial edge colors, but that conflicts with the dynamic edge coloring in `visNetwork`.

Let me first let you know that I work in R a lot, but am certainly not a programmer so this may not be the best way to go about it. Given that *a solution* is to just declare both the initial and dynamic colors directly within `VisEdges`:

```
library(visNetwork)

# Create example data
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4, label = c("Node 1", "Node 2", "Node 3", "Node 4"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), to = c(2, 3, 4, 3, 4), value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))

# Create visNetwork object with customized node and edge colors
visNetwork(nodes, edges) |>  
  visNodes(color = list(background = "skyblue", border = "black", highlight = "yellow", hover = "yellow")) |> 
  visEdges(color = list(color = ifelse(edges$value <= 20, "blue", "red"), 
                        highlight = "yellow", 
                        hover = "yellow"), 
           smooth = FALSE) |>
  visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = TRUE, hover = TRUE),
             nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

I hope this helps!