# How to get a set of edges with attributes starting from a list of nodes in igraph?

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, edges

I have a large igraph where the vertex of interest were extracted, then out of that subgraph, nodes with the `description` of interest were extracted.
Now I want to extract the edges with attributes corresponding to those nodes with the description of interest.

I tried with `edges.table <- E(subgraphGRN)[from(genes$Names)]` but I would like to get the attributes as well.
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918955/display-edge-label-only-when-hovering-over-it-with-cursor-visnetwork-igraph

Comment: this would be with visnetwork though which I think you'll like better

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but since I am thinking to implement a webpage for this script, I don't want to jump between packages. The less I have to update packages, the better. That's why I prefer to stick to `igraph`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `E(subgraphGRN)[[from(genes$Names)]]` with double brackets. Double brackets provides you with all the information of the edge vector.

Also, maybe `E(subgraphGRN)[[from(genes$Names)]] %>% subgraph.edges(graph = subgraphGRN, eids = .) %>% as_data_frame()` if you want to use the information for non-graph processing.